# GAS: Create GIF from array PNG using FireStore compose

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

lately I have been having problems using ".../compose", can anyone help me?
At the moment I have come to create this JSON object

```
opzioni={
  "kind": "storage#composeRequest",
  "sourceObjects": [
    {
      "name":""
    },
    {
      "name":""
    }
  ],
  "destination": {
    "contentType": "image/gif"
  }
}
```

My problem is that as soon as I send the request I get a gif which, however, is only the first PNG that is recovered, it only converts the first image. This is the code

```
function composeGIF(){
  
  //Variables
  var opzioni,json,url,parameters,string;

  //file JSON
  opzioni={
    "kind": "storage#composeRequest",
    "sourceObjects": [
      {
        "name":""
      },
      {
        "name":""
      }
    ],
    "destination": {
      "contentType": "image/gif"
    }
  }
  string = JSON.stringify(opzioni);
  json=JSON.parse(string);
  
  //Storage URL for compose. BUCKET needs to be replaced
  url="https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o/destinationObject/compose";

  //Request and authorization
  parameters = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: string,
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  };

  //Audit log
  console.log(json);

  //Send
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parameters);
}
```

I would like to get a gif file inside my bucket.
Thank you so much to anyone who can help me out.

*Translated with google translator*

Comment: I have no idea how it works. But the half-empty array of `sourceObjects` looks strange. Shouldn't it contain something?

Comment: I wanted to leave the array empty because in addition to the position of the file inside the bucket it allows me to insert only "generation" and "ifGenerationMatch" inside "objectPreconditions".
{
  "kind": "storage#composeRequest",
  "sourceObjects": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "generation": "long",
      "objectPreconditions": {
        "ifGenerationMatch": "long"
      }
    }
  ],
  "destination": objects Resource
}